# PayPal Button Error in Android Application

Tags: java, android, eclipse, paypal

I am trying to get PayPal button work at Checkout Activity in my Android App. But I am getting a Null Pointer Exception, It refers to line 1585 in my code. The logcat output is as follows:

```
03-22 21:27:28.659: W/dalvikvm(419): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
03-22 21:27:28.669: E/AndroidRuntime(419): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-22 21:27:28.669: E/AndroidRuntime(419): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-22 21:27:28.669: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:406)
03-22 21:27:28.669: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at com.fokrul.justdeals.ActivityTab$PaypalTask$1.onClick(ActivityTab.java:1585)
03-22 21:27:28.669: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3110)
03-22 21:27:28.669: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at com.paypal.android.MEP.CheckoutButton.onClick(Unknown Source)
03-22 21:27:28.669: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3110)
03-22 21:27:28.669: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11934)
03-22 21:27:28.669: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-22 21:27:28.669: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-22 21:27:28.669: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
03-22 21:27:28.669: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
03-22 21:27:28.669: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-22 21:27:28.669: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
03-22 21:27:28.669: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
03-22 21:27:28.669: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
03-22 21:27:28.669: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My Code for Onclick method for PayPal activity is below:

```
class PaypalTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        protected final char[] TOTAL_GBP = null;

        public Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            ppObject = PayPal.initWithAppID(getBaseContext(), "APP-80W284485P519543T", PayPal.ENV_SANDBOX);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            btnPaypal = ppObject.getCheckoutButton(getApplicationContext(), PayPal.BUTTON_278x43, CheckoutButton.TEXT_PAY);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            btnPaypal.setLayoutParams(params);
            rlPay.addView(btnPaypal);
            if(utils.prefs.getBoolean("isLogged", false)) btnPaypal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); else btnPaypal.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            btnPaypal.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    // to check whether there are any books in the shopping cart
                    if(!cid.isEmpty()){
                        PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment();
            <<LINE 1585-->>>>> payment.setSubtotal(new BigDecimal(TOTAL_GBP));
                        payment.setCurrencyType("USD");
                        payment.setRecipient(Utils.PAYPAL_ACCOUNT);
                        payment.setPaymentType(PayPal.PAYMENT_TYPE_GOODS);
                        Intent checkoutIntent = PayPal.getInstance().checkout(payment, getBaseContext());
                        startActivityForResult(checkoutIntent, 1);
                    }else{
                        utils.showToast("Your shopping cart is empty.");
                        // The PayPal button needs to be updated so that the user can click on it again.
                        btnPaypal.updateButton();
                    }
                }   
            });
        }
    }
```

Any thoughts what might be going wrong here?

Comment: it means that your TOTAL_GBP is `null` you can not pass null as a constructor parameter :)

Comment: @Sergey Benner Thanks!!What value I can assign to TOTAL_GBP then? If I change it into int type, PayPal gives `Invalid Payment Type` Error!

Comment: Try usual payment.setSubtotal(new BigDecimal("8.25")); check this link too http://androiddevelopement.blogspot.com/2011/04/adding-paypal-payment-in-android.html

Comment: @Sergey Benner YOU ARE A STAR!! Well Explained and IT WORKED :)

Comment: If you can answer it then I can vote it for you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious answer is a recap from comments:

`protected final char[] TOTAL_GBP = null;`

dont set `null` as a constructor parameter for BigDecimal(TOTAL_GBP) 
@payment.setSubtotal(new BigDecimal(TOTAL_GBP));

example:
`payment.setSubtotal(new BigDecimal("8.25"));`
taken from here http://androiddevelopement.blogspot.com/2011/04/adding-paypal-payment-in-android.html about paypal and android integration.

The last but not least:

You might also want to rethink your `AsyncTask` process and `doInBackground()` method
and your `onPostExecute()` you usually don't set `onClick()` listeners in the `AsyncTask`.
They should rather have to be in your Activity and running in your main thread then
within a button click you may call on execution of the `AsyncTask`.

More on AsyncTasks :
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html
[AsyncTask Android example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example)

---

Hope it clarifies the matter a bit.

Cheers

Comment: BEST ANSWER TO MY QUESTION! :)